# Crystal Reports using the Formula Fields in Basic syntax Editor - How do I use an outer if statement?

Tags: crystal-reports

I am new to Crystal and do not use visual basic, but I need to get this report written.

I have one table that I need to check surfaces to determine which path to follow.

Basically,

If surface <500 follow path to check a tooth number and calculate differently than 
If surface  >500 and <1000 follow path to check tooth number with different calcuation

There are too many variables of tooth/surface to add the outer check to each tooth line so I was trying to wrap an if around each different grouping of of surfaces

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Surface and Tooth are tables? What's involved in "following a path" or "checking a tooth number?"

Answer (score 0):

If the calculation for determining the tooth number depends only on the single surface value, why not do something like this? Sorry if this is an oversimplification...

```
If {Tooth.Surface} < 500 Then 
    formula=[Do something here] 'Surface is less than 500
ElseIf {Tooth.Surface} < 1000 Then
    formula=[Do something different] 'Surface is between 500 and 999
Else 
    formula=[And something else] 'Surface is 1000 or greater
End If
```